# Symfony string field in schema results in MySQL TEXT field

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, schema

I am using symfony 1.4 and have a field in a table with this definition:

```
subject: { type: string(300), fixed: false, notnull: true }
```

The migration generated from this is:

```
'subject' =>
            array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => '0',
             'notnull' => '1',
             'length' => '300',
            ),
```

Running this migration creates MySQL DDL code which sets the subject field to be of type `TEXT` rather than `varchar(300)`.

However, if I change the `300` to `200` the migration creates a field of type `varchar(200)`.

Is there a way to force symfony/doctrine to create this field as a `varchar(300)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without editing the code of doctrine.

[`Doctrine_Connection_Mysql`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Connection/Mysql.php#L86) says the maximum length of varchar fields is 255 characters. This is true for mysql before 5.0.3, and doctrine uses this value for compatibility reasons.